# What is this associative algebra with two generators and one defining relation?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

> Let $A$ be an associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra with two generators $E$, $H$, and one defining relation $HE - EH = 2E$.

**Question.** Does this algebra have a name, and what is its significance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983204/name-of-this-associative-mathbbc-algebra-formulas/), this algebra is the [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) of a [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra), this time the unique nonabelian $2$-dimensional Lie algebra. One way to describe it is as the [Borel subalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_subgroup) of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$: explicitly, it is the Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ spanned by

$$H = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{array} \right], E = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right].$$

You can check for yourself that $[H, E] = HE - EH = 2E$.

If we write $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ then it's common to denote the Borel subalgebra by $\mathfrak{b}$ and the universal enveloping algebra by $U(-)$, so that this algebra would be called $U(\mathfrak{b})$. It naturally occurs in the study of the representation theory of $\mathfrak{g}$, or equivalently the study of modules over $U(\mathfrak{g})$; see  [Verma module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verma_module) for some details.